# How to read a binary file which has some text string in it in using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, binary

I have a file whose name is `142490.1` and that file will have content like this -

```
^A^A^@^@^@=^@^@=y^B^@e^A^C^@f^B^HÂ¬^\ÂA^Y^A^G^B<81>s
^A^@G@client.1424906160996.30431.DC1.5faa5c2a-c382-40b8-baa8-234a8e6ecd19^@^@^A^F<8b>f^@Ã¸^@y^@^@^AKÃ^F<86>T^@^@^@ÃªÃµ^A\^@^R304344351^N2047675^@^D77^@^Y^W^B^@
27.99^@^X261449949761^@Ã^O^@<92>^NICHOLSON Baseball     ^V|t -S M L XL XXL(2)^@
15724^@
63862^U^GÃ°V11450^@^B7^@<9a>^A^@^L823196^@Â¨<99>Â´Â°Ã¸R^B^@^TBj%2FRZUw*^@^PBoZf8jU*^@^T1032869222^B^@&LH_DefaultDomain_77^@^@^A^@^@H@client.1424906160992.116975.DC1.344073e8-93f6-487c-b343-7923080f07aa^@^@^AKÃ^F<8b>f^@Â­^@y^@^@^AKÃ^EÃ²<9f>Â£^AX^@^T1169755138^N2047935^@^B3.^W^@Ã°^?^B^@^H0.99^@^X171689807229^B^@rTOPSHOP LEATHER 3 EU 36^B^B^@
45333^B^B^@^F^@^L161103^@Ã°ÃÂ¯Â°Ã¸R^B^B^@^PBosZQlE*^B^B^B^@^@^A^@^@G@client.1424906160976.1295684.DC1.66a6ca77-30ee-4d50-b7ea-4a524eb94af1^@^@^AKÃ^F<8b>f^@Â¤^@y^@^@^AKÃ^F<89>^O^@^@^@<96><9a>^AT^@^R129569484^N2047935^@^B3^]^V^B^@^F499^853759648^B^@bWILLIS AND^B^B^@
20489^B^B^@^F^@^P-1404420^@<9e>Â¤Â´Â°Ã¸R^B^B^@^PBop4ml0*^B^B^B^@^@^A^@^@H@client.1424906160989.104826.DC1.4d58c06a-3526-408a-a48b-8bdc82b94dba^@^@^AKÃ^F<8b>f^@Â¨^@R^@^@^AKÃ^F<83>Â¶^@^@^@<9a>Â·^AX^@^T1048328026^N2045573^@^B0.^W^@^P^B^B^^AÃ°@^@^H6000^@^Z1955 corvette^@Ã¬<8e>Â´Â°Ã¸R^B^@^PBiZzFm8*^@^PBoO8YKc*^@^@^A^@
```

I know above file content looks mainly binary but there are some strings in the file which we can read it clearly.

If you see the above file content, you will see a string like this -

```
@client.1424906160996.30431.DC1.5faa5c2a-c382-40b8-baa8-234a8e6ecd19
```

In the above string `1424906160996` is a timestamp.

**ProblemStatement:**

I need to find all the strings which starts with `@client` and whose timestamp is one minute old as compared to current timestamp.

Let's say if below are the strings which starts with `@client` and whose timestamp is one minute older as compared to current timestamp, then it should print out like this after reading the file -

```
@client.1424906161996.3031.DC1.5faaa-c382-40b8-baa8-234a8ed19
@client.1424906162996.3041.DC1.5a5c2a-c382-40b8-baa8-238e6ec9
@client.1424906163996.3043231.DC1.5faa2a-c382-40b8-baa8-23e6ed19
@client.1424906164996.3016731.DC1.5faa5a-c382-40b8-baa8-234ad19
```

Is there any way to do this using shell script which can read the above file and print out those strings which starts with `@client` and whose timestamp is older than 1 minute.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something with `strings`, it only keep printable ASCII characters from your file :

```
strings - 142490.1 |
  awk -F '.' -v timestamp="$(date +%s)" '/^@client/ && $2 < (timestamp - 60)*1000 {print}'
```

This awk script may be too specific to this example : it look at the field between the first and the second dot, and consider it's the timestamp.
If it's less than the current timestamp - 60 seconds, it print the line.

Hope it helped.

EDIT :
As noted by Thomas Dickey (I'm new here, I don't know how to make a real reference to your account), you have to use the `-` flag on `strings`

EDIT2 :
After a few attempts, we reached a working version by adapting another answer from @ThomasDickey

```
FILE=1424911080.1
strings - $FILE |
  awk -v fileTs="${FILE%.*}000" '/@client/ { ts = $0 ; sub("^.*@client\.","", ts); sub("\..*$","",ts); if ( ts - fileTs > 500 || ts - fileTs < -500 ) { print $0; } }'
```

Finally, to have the percentage of lines that have a timestamp difference > 500 :

```
FILE=1424911080.1
tot=$(strings - "$FILE" | grep '@client' |wc -l)
old=$(strings - "$FILE" |
  awk -v fileTs="${FILE%.*}000" '/@client/ { ts = $0 ; sub("^.*@client\.","", ts); sub("\..*$","",ts); if ( ts - fileTs > 500 || ts - fileTs < -500 ) { print $0; } }' |
  wc -l)

echo "old : $(( old * 100 / tot ))%"
```

Comment: If you don't use the "-" option, strings assumes it is an executable file, and will omit parts.

Comment: @CorentinPeuvrel I tried this but it printed out bunch of stuff as well which doesn't start with `@client`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Try to replace the awk script by `/^@client/ && $2 < (timestamp - 60)*1000 {print}`. I didn't checked that it was a line starting with `@client`

Comment: @CorentinPeuvrel Can you edit that as well for the sake of completeness?

Comment: As I said, "strings" is the simplest way - as a caveat it sometimes adds trailing junk if the strings are not null-terminated.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I see undestood now.

Comment: @CorentinPeuvrel After I tried your recent suggestion, it's not printing out anything. Looks like I might be off what I was trying to do. I guess I need to print out `@client` strings whose difference between current timestamp and timestamp in the string is greater than 1 minute.

Comment: Try `strings - 142490.1 | awk -F '.' '/^@client/ {print $2}'`, just to see if, without the check on the timestamp, we really get something (and, by adding the `$2` after the print, we'll see what is identified as the timestamp)

Comment: I just tried it and I didn't got anything back. looks like something is wrong. When I opened the file, I can see there are strings with @client.

Comment: Maybe the line doesn't really start with '@client'. Could you try `strings - 142490.1 | awk -F '.' '/@client/ {print $2}'` (the same except we just match lines with "@client" instead of starting with it)

Comment: @CorentinPeuvrel Yup now it worked fine. Indeed it doesn't starts with `@client`.

Comment: Ok, so it's a little more complicated, we cannot assume that the timestamp will be the second field, so we have to do something like what @ThomasDickey proposed. I cannot comment yet, but in his script, I would have used a awk variable for $TS with `awk -v sysTs="$(date +%s)000" '/@client/ { ts = gensub("^.*@client\.","", "", $0); sub("\..*$","",ts); if ( ts >= sysTs - 60 and ts < sysTs ) { print $0; } }'`  (I also merge the first two instructions in one gensub)

Comment: Btw, I think the timestamp condition is the opposite of what you said. You wanted line "older" than T-1min, is that it ? So the `if` should be `if ( ts < sysTs - 60)`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to extract the data is by using the [strings](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) utility, telling it to scan the whole file, e.g.,

```
strings - inputfile | egrep '@client(\.[[:xdigit:]]+)+(-[[:xdigit:]]+)+'
```

but as noted in the other example, there is still the timestamp to consider.  That can be done by piping the raw data through awk, e.g.,

```
awk '/@client/ { ts = $0; sub("^.*@client.","",ts); sub("\..*$","",ts); if ( ts >= '$TS' - 60 and ts < '$TS' ) { print $0; } }'
```

where $TS is the value that you are looking for (a range makes more sense than equality).

Actually the egrep is redundant (awk/mawk/gawk can do character classes unless you're using the obsolete version from Ubuntu).  But it helps to break the process into stages to check that they work.  In the awk script,

- it starts with a simple pattern /@client/
- I'm not certain strings will return this at the beginning of a line, but then
- assign the line contents $0 to a variable which I can modify,
- trim off the part through "@client."
- trim off the part beginning with "." (is that milliseconds?)
- compare the value to the $TS variable (passed in as part of the script, though another recent posting reminds us that awk's "-v" option would work too).
- if it passes the comparison, print the original line

As an aside, I'm aware that awk has a "-v" option, but since I generally build up scripts using the simplest tool which works first (such as sed), I generally do direct substitution by habit, saving "-v" for scripts passed as separate files.  I did (long ago) run into an awk which did not support "-v" -- see [changelog](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20020112)).  But we can take for granted that it is there.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I didn't got any output on the console. In your suggestion how can I do the check for timestamp as well?

Comment: The timestamp check is in the second chunk of script -- I'll add some text to help.

Comment: How will I pass $TS variable value?

Comment: One more thing, looks like I might be off what I was trying to do. I guess I need to print out `@client` strings whose difference between current timestamp and timestamp in the string is greater than 1 minute.

Comment: In the example I gave, $TS would be an ordinary shell variable, e.g., TS=1424906161996 (awk user-defined variables do not begin with "$").